# Using a MySQL View to Retrieve Running Total

Tags: mysql, database, view

We're building an e-commerce system and we need some help in deciding on what's the best way to determine how many stocks are available per product.

Say we have the tables "products", "products_in", and "products_out". "products_in" records all our transactions that increase the quantities of our products (e.g. when we buy the products from our wholesale suppliers). While "products_out" records all our transactions that decrease the quantities of our products (e.g. when our customers buy the products).

In our apps, retrieving the quantities available for our products is more common than writing/updating records in the "products_in" and "products_out" tables. Given this, will the use of a MySQL view that depends on "products_in" and "products_out" and computes the available stock be more efficient than computing it on the fly every time we query it? Will the value on the view be recomputed every time there's a new record in "products_in" or "products_out"? Or will the view recompute the value every time we query it (which can be quite expensive in our case)?

Answer (score 0):

> will the use of a MySQL view that depends on "products_in" and "products_out" and computes the available stock be more efficient than computing it on the fly every time we query it? Will the value on the view be recomputed every time there's a new record in "products_in" or "products_out"? Or will the view recompute the value every time we query it (which can be quite expensive in our case)?

Let's think of the db steps in each case:

**Case 1** If you compute `available_stock` every time a product comes in or goes out and store it in say `product` table

1. If product comes in, `Insert` queries in `product_in` table or if product goes out, `Insert` queries in `product_out` table
2. In either case, Update queries in `available_stock` column of product. (Assume here if 10 products come or 10 products go, there will be 10 individual queries that will be fired) - Expensive?

**Case 2** If you compute `available_stock` in view everytime and not store it in database

1. Fetch records from `product_in` and `product_out` tables (only for few products for which you want `available_stock`), do some math, and display the estimated stock - Expensive?

I personally would go with case 2, because it involves less db transactions overall then case 1 which involves tons of transactions to keep the stock in sync.

**Footnote** In the sidelines, I'd definitely say that if you are hardcore 'Object Oriented Programmer' then your db mappings definitely violates the fundamentals.  `Products_in`, `Products_out` are both the same entities (objects) that records the inventory/stock transactions (like `Father`,`Mother` entities are `Persons`), therefore you should make them encapsulated into one general table `ProductInOutData`.

In `ProductInOutData`, you can then add an enum having either `in` value or `out` value. Having both `in` and `out` records in one table will not only improve the readability and accessibility but also will help in easy calculation of the products coming in or going out making the case 2 more lightweight.